# Powershell array to hashtable cannot get key's value with bracket notation but dotting works?

Tags: arrays, powershell, dictionary, hashtable

I am trying to mutate an array into key-value pairs as a hashtable, this procedure seems to create a list of hashtables but they act almost as intended. How can I go about and create a single hashtable as intended? coming from python, I was expecting something similar to dict comprehension..

```
PS > ('1','2','3') | foreach {@{($_+'A') = $_}}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
1A                             1
2A                             2
3A                             3

PS > (('1','2','3') | foreach {@{($_+'A') = $_}}).'1A'
1
PS > (('1','2','3') | foreach {@{($_+'A') = $_}})['1A']
```

- empty last line is $null rather than 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Your pipeline emits an *array of*<sup>[1]</sup> `[hashtable]` instances**, constructing a [hashtable literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) in every iteration.
- **[Member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration)** - i.e. the ability to access a property at the *collection* level and have the *elements'* property values returned - **only works with `.`**, the [member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-), **not also with `[...]`**, the [index operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#index-operator--)

  - See [GitHub issue #17514](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17514) for a discussion of this asymmetry, which was declared to be *by design*.
  - In other words: your pipeline is the equivalent of the following, which looks for a '1A' property (key) on each hashtable and returns only the value from the one that has such a key:<sup>[2]</sup>

    ```bash
    # Works, but only due to use of . rather than []
    @(
      @{ '1A' = 1 }
      @{ '2A' = 2 }
      @{ '3A' = 3 }
    ).'1A' # -> 1
    ```

---

If, by contrast, your intent was to **emit a *single* hashtable instance**, use the following, which then allows you to use dot and index notation interchangeably:

```bash
(
  ('1','2','3') |
  foreach { $ht = @{} } { $ht[$_+'A'] = $_ } { $ht }
)['1A'] # -> 1
```

Note the use of *three* script blocks with `foreach` ([`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)), which bind to the `-Begin`, `-Process`, and `-End` parameters, respectively. The `-Begin` block initializes a hashtable, the `-Process` block adds entries to it, and the `-End` block emits the now-filled hashtable.
Note that the `$ht` variable will linger in the caller's scope, which is probably desired here; however, you can use `{ $ht; Remove-Variable ht }` as the `-End` block to prevent that.

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, it *streams* multiple instances are to the success output stream, which, when captured via `(...)`, become an `[object[]]` array.</sup>

<sup>[2] Elements that do not have the requested property are simply *skipped* during member-access enumeration, with one exception due
to a *bug*: `[pscustomobject]` instances unexpectedly contribute a `$null` value to the output - see [GitHub issue #13752](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13752).</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering about the last part with remove-variable you mentioned. It resolves my concerns now.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function that I think covers most of my expectations regarding python like dictionary comprehension.
see https://gist.github.com/YoraiLevi/292bb8d0e2ce0f87d37e5d5d735fff16

```
function ConvertTo-Hashtable {
    <#
    .LINK
    https://gist.github.com/YoraiLevi/292bb8d0e2ce0f87d37e5d5d735fff16

    .LINK
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265408/powershell-array-to-hashtable-cannot-get-keys-value-with-bracket-notation-but-d

    .LINK
    https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/

    .SYNOPSIS
    Converts input objects into a hashtable.
    
    .DESCRIPTION
    The ConvertTo-Hashtable function converts input objects into a hashtable. It can be used to create a hashtable from an array of values or from pipeline input. The function takes a scriptblock that is used to generate the hashtable values. The scriptblock is executed for each input object and must output a single hashtable. The function can handle duplicate keys in the input objects and provides options for how to handle them.
    
    .PARAMETER ScriptBlock
    The scriptblock that is used to generate the hashtable values. The scriptblock is executed for each input object and must output a single hashtable.
    
    .PARAMETER InputArray
    An array of input objects to convert to a hashtable.
    
    .PARAMETER InputObject
    An input object to convert to a hashtable.
    
    .PARAMETER DuplicateKeyAction
    Specifies how to handle duplicate keys in the input objects. Valid values are 'Stop', 'Ignore', 'Overwrite', 'Append', and 'Prepend'. The default value is 'Stop'.
    
    .EXAMPLE
    ConvertTo-Hashtable 1, 2, 3
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    3                              3
    2                              2
    1                              1
    
    .EXAMPLE
    1, 2, 3 | ConvertTo-Hashtable
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    3                              3
    2                              2
    1                              1
    
    .EXAMPLE
    1, 2, 3 | ConvertTo-Hashtable { @{($_ + 1) = $_ } }
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    4                              3
    3                              2
    2                              1
    
    .EXAMPLE
    1, 2, 3 | ConvertTo-Hashtable { @{($PSItem + 1) = $PSItem } }
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    4                              3
    3                              2
    2                              1
    
    .EXAMPLE
    1, 2, 3 | ConvertTo-Hashtable { @{($args[0] + 1) = $args[0] } }
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    4                              3
    3                              2
    2                              1
    
    .EXAMPLE
    1, 2, 3 | ConvertTo-Hashtable { @{($input[0] + 1) = $input[0] } }
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    4                              3
    3                              2
    2                              1
    
    .EXAMPLE
    1, '2', 3 | ConvertTo-Hashtable { if ($_ -is [int]) { @{$_ = $_ } } else { [pscustomobject]@{} } }
    
    Scriptblock execution resulted in an error/exception: 'Provided scriptblock must only output a single hashtable, but output type was System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'
    
    .EXAMPLE
    1, '2', 3 | ConvertTo-Hashtable { if ($_ -is [int]) { @{$_ = $_ } } else { Write-Error 'Write-Error example' } }
    
    Scriptblock execution resulted in an error/exception: 'Write-Error example'
    
    .EXAMPLE
    1, '2', '3' | ConvertTo-Hashtable { if ($_ -is [int]) { @{$_ = $_ } }else { throw 'throw example' } }
    
    Scriptblock execution resulted in an error/exception: 'throw example'
    
    .EXAMPLE
    1, $null, 3 | ConvertTo-Hashtable { @{$_ = $_ } }
    
    Scriptblock execution resulted in an error/exception: 'A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.'
    
    .EXAMPLE
    $i = 0
    ConvertTo-Hashtable 1, 1, 1, 2 { @{$_ = ($_ + $i) } ; $i++; }
    
    Scriptblock execution resulted in an error/exception: Key '1' was found multiple times
    
    .EXAMPLE
    $i = 0
    ConvertTo-Hashtable 1, 1, 1, 2 { @{$_ = $_ + $i } ; $i++; } -DuplicateKeyAction Stop
    
    Scriptblock execution resulted in an error/exception: Key '1' was found multiple times
    
    .EXAMPLE
    $i = 0
    ConvertTo-Hashtable 1, 1, 1, 2 { @{$_ = $_ + $i } ; $i++; } -DuplicateKeyAction Ignore
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    2                              5
    1                              1
    
    .EXAMPLE
    $i = 0
    ConvertTo-Hashtable 1, 1, 1, 2 { @{$_ = $_ + $i } ; $i++; } -DuplicateKeyAction Overwrite
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    2                              5
    1                              3
    
    .EXAMPLE
    $i = 0
    ConvertTo-Hashtable 1, 1, 1, 2 { @{$_ = $_ + $i } ; $i++; } -DuplicateKeyAction Append
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    2                              {5}
    1                              {1, 2, 3}
    
    .EXAMPLE
    $i = 0
    ConvertTo-Hashtable 1, 1, 1, 2 { @{$_ = $_ + $i } ; $i++; } -DuplicateKeyAction Prepend
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    2                              {5}
    1                              {3, 2, 1}

    #>
    [CmdletBinding( DefaultParameterSetName = 'Pipeline')]
    param(
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Call', Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Pipeline', Position = 0)]
        [scriptblock]$ScriptBlock = { @{$_ = $_ } }, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = 'Call')]
        [array]$InputArray,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Pipeline')]
        [psobject]$InputObject,
        [ValidateSet('Stop', 'Ignore', 'Overwrite', 'Append', 'Prepend')]
        [string]$DuplicateKeyAction = 'Stop'
    )
    begin {
        $ht = @{}
    }
    process {
        try {
            $InputObject = switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
                'Call' {
                    $InputArray
                }
                'Pipeline' {
                    @($InputObject)
                }
            }
            $tables = $InputObject | ForEach-Object {
                try {
                    $PreviousErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
                    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
                    $table = Invoke-Command -NoNewScope -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -InputObject $_ -ArgumentList $_
                    $ErrorActionPreference = $PreviousErrorActionPreference
                }
                catch {
                    $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(
                        [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
                                ([System.ArgumentException]::New("Scriptblock execution resulted in an error/exception: '$($PSItem.Exception.Message)'", $_)),
                            'ScriptBlockException',
                            [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidResult,
                            $ScriptBlock
                        )
                    )
                }
                if ($table -isnot [System.Collections.IDictionary]) {
                    $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(
                        [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
                                ([System.ArgumentException]::New("Provided scriptblock must only output a single hashtable, but output type was $($table.GetType())")),
                            'ArgumentException',
                            [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidResult,
                            $ScriptBlock
                        )
                    )
                }
                $table
            }
            $tables | ForEach-Object {
                $table = $_
                $table.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
                    $Key = $_.Key
                    switch ($DuplicateKeyAction) {
                        'Stop' {
                            if (!$ht.ContainsKey($Key)) {
                                $Value = $table.$key
                            }
                            else {
                                $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(
                                    [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
                                                ([System.ArgumentException]::New("Key '$($Key)' was found multiple times")),
                                        'ArgumentException',
                                        [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidData,
                                        $Key
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        'Ignore' {
                            if (!$ht.ContainsKey($Key)) {
                                $Value = $table.$key
                            }
                            else {
                                $Value = $ht.$key
                            }
                        }
                        'Overwrite' { $Value = $table.$key }
                        'Append' {
                            if (!$ht.ContainsKey($Key)) {
                                $Value = @(, $table.$key)

                            }
                            else {
                                $Value = ($ht.$key + @(, $table.$key))
                            }
                        }
                        'Prepend' {
                            if (!$ht.ContainsKey($Key)) {
                                $Value = @(, $table.$key)
                            }
                            else {
                                $Value = (@(, $table.$key) + $ht.$key)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $ht.$Key = $Value
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($PSItem)
        }
    }
    end {
        return $ht
    }
}
```